# What experiment can I do at home to show different formation of spiral galaxy and elliptical galaxy?

Tags: home-experiment, galaxies

I am wondering if there is a simple experiment that can be performed at home to demonstrate the formation of galaxy with arms and no arms(density is smoothly spread out)? The experiment must help explain the actual formation of these two distinct galaxies.